# Invalid hook call ao utilizar função em componente ReactJS

Tags: react, next.js

Tenho um componente chamado Modal(), e estou tentando acioná-lo em outro componente, através do comportamento "onClick".

Como posso criar um componente deste tipo, acionável a partir qualquer outro componente? O que preciso alterar?

Independente se importo o openModal ou o Modal, ele dá erros diferentes.

Se importo o openModal, dá erro no onClick:

> Unhandled Runtime Error - Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be
> called inside of the body of a function component.

E se importo o Modal, dá este erro ao carregar a página:

> Unhandled Runtime Error - ReferenceError: openModal is not defined

Estou usando:

- React 17.0.2
- NextJS 12.0.7

Vou reduzir o código do componente  só para o que interessa, no caso.

```
Componente <Hero> (/components/pages/index/hero.js)

import openModal from '../../global/modal'

export default function Hero() {
    
    return (
        <>
           <a onClick={openModal}>Abrir modal</a>
        </>
    )
}
```

modal.js

```
import { Dialog, Transition } from '@headlessui/react'
import { Fragment, useState } from 'react'

export default function Modal() {
  let [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true)

  function closeModal() {
    setIsOpen(false)
  }

  function openModal() {
    setIsOpen(true)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Transition appear show={isOpen} as={Fragment}>
        <Dialog
          as="div"
          className="fixed inset-0 z-10 overflow-y-auto"
          onClose={closeModal}
        >
          <div className="min-h-screen px-4 text-center">
            <Transition.Child
              as={Fragment}
              enter="ease-out duration-300"
              enterFrom="opacity-0"
              enterTo="opacity-100"
              leave="ease-in duration-200"
              leaveFrom="opacity-100"
              leaveTo="opacity-0"
            >
              <Dialog.Overlay className="fixed inset-0" />
            </Transition.Child>

            {/* This element is to trick the browser into centering the modal contents. */}
            <span
              className="inline-block h-screen align-middle"
              aria-hidden="true"
            >
              &#8203;
            </span>
            <Transition.Child
              as={Fragment}
              enter="ease-out duration-300"
              enterFrom="opacity-0 scale-95"
              enterTo="opacity-100 scale-100"
              leave="ease-in duration-200"
              leaveFrom="opacity-100 scale-100"
              leaveTo="opacity-0 scale-95"
            >
              <div className="inline-block w-full max-w-md p-6 my-8 overflow-hidden text-left align-middle transition-all transform bg-white shadow-xl rounded-2xl">
                <Dialog.Title
                  as="h3"
                  className="text-lg font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900"
                >
                  Título do modal
                </Dialog.Title>
                <div className="mt-2">
                  <p className="text-sm text-gray-500">
                    Texto do modal
                  </p>
                </div>

                <div className="mt-4">
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="inline-flex justify-center px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-blue-900 bg-blue-100 border border-transparent rounded-md hover:bg-blue-200 focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-offset-2 focus-visible:ring-blue-500"
                    onClick={closeModal}
                  >
                    Fechar
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Transition.Child>
          </div>
        </Dialog>
      </Transition>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Modal` é um componente, ele precisa ser chamado como um JSX (`<Modal />`) não como uma função

Há 2 formas de fazer isso, uma é tendo um estado dentro do componente pai pra renderizar ou não o modal:

```
import Modal from '../../global/modal'

export default function Hero() {
    let [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true)

    return (
        <>
            <a onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>Abrir modal</a>

            { isOpen ? <Modal /> : null }
        </>
    )
}
```

É a forma que o React encoraja fazer, mas tem o problema de precisar ter um estado no componente pai, que, geralmente, não é preciso

A outra forma é usar uma função pra renderizar o componente em outro lugar da árvore:

```
function openModal() {
    ReactDOM.render(<Modal />, document.querySelector('#modal-container'));
}

// Uso:
<a onClick={() => openModal()}>Abrir modal</a>
```

Nessa forma é mais simples de usar mas pode haver problemas com os contextos já que o modal não estará dentro do componente pai na árvore DOM. Dá pra fazer algo semelhante utilizando contextos, tendo um Provider que vai renderizar o container dos modais e um Consumer que irá "avisar" o Provider pra renderizar um novo modal